# How to use -proxy option explicitly with OpenSSL in RHEL 7

Tags: centos7, openssl, rhel7

unable to use -proxy option in openssl command on RHEL7 server, same is working fine on RHEL8 is there any other way to use proxy with Openssl.

Below is the command used.

[root@testvm01 ~]# openssl s_client -proxy 192.168.1.11:80 -connect jira-server.msteams-atlassian.com:443
unknown option -proxy
usage: s_client args